# remove dynamically created collection jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello i am displaying a collection that is dynamically created and I want to remove them when a delete button is clicked i want to fade off and remove that particular ul collection.When i tried to do it, it removes every collection.Thanks for the help

```
<div class="row">
                <div id='result'>
                    {% for w in newList %}
                    <ul class="collection" id="{{ w['id'] }}">
                            <li class="collection-item avatar">
                              <img src ="{{ w['url'] }}" style="max-height: 100px" alt="wine Image" class="circle">
                              <span class="title">{{ w['name'] }}</span>
                              <p><i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
                              </p>
                              <p> <i class="material-icons">attach_money</i>{{w['price']}}</p>
                              <a href="#" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons deleteBtn" wineID="{{ w['id'] }}">delete</i></a>
                            </li>
                      </ul>
{% endfor %}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result').on('click','.deleteBtn',function(){
    let wineID=$(this).attr('wineID');
    console.log(wineID);
    req=$.ajax({
    url:'/deleteWine',
    type:'POST',
    data:{ id:wineID }
    })
    $('.collection').fadeOut(300,function(){closest(this).remove()})
})
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're essentially doing a `$('.collection').closest().remove()` which will remove the `closest()` parent to each element with a collection class on it.

You need to specify the relevant id using a `$('#<id here>')` to only delete the relevant element's parent.

Also, you should move the line that's doing the `closest().remove()` inside the `deleteBtn` click event handler method.